# How to highlight the data points in ggplot2 package<mpg dataset that are outside the linear trend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have already used the code for plotting-

```
ggplot(mpg, aes (x= displ, y= hwy)) + 
geom_point()
```

and the scatter plot has already been obtained. However, I want to highlight the bottom right                                                                                                                                                     points that are different from the general linear trend of the plotting.

Comment: what is your criteria for "outside the linear trend"?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using the package ggrepel with `geom_label_repel` function. You can create a label of what you want per point if necessary. You can change the condition to whatever you want. I added a linear line using `geom_smooth`. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
# create highlight dataframe
highlight_df <- mpg %>% filter(displ > 6 & hwy > 20 & hwy < 30)

# Create certain label
highlight_df$your_label <- "label"

ggplot(mpg, aes(x= displ, y= hwy)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  geom_label_repel(highlight_df, mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, label = your_label), color = "red", segment.color = "grey")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful:

```
library(ggplot)
library(gghighlight)

ggplot(mpg) + 
geom_point(aes(displ, hwy)) + 
gghighlight(displ > 5, hwy > 17)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/05/how-to-highlight-select-data-points-with-ggplot2-in-r/

```
highlight_df <-mpg%>%
+filter(hwy>=20,displ>=5) 

ggplot(mpg, aes (x= displ, y= hwy))+ geom_point(alpha=0.3)+
geom_point(data=highlight_df,aes(x=displ,y=hwy),color='red',size=3)
```